# Query evaluation in class show

Tags: haskell

I'm working on a project and I need a little help, please!

```
type CSV = String
type Table = [[String]]

table_csv :: Table -> CSV
csv_table :: CSV -> Table

data query = CSV CSV | Table Table | List [String]
```

How can I enroll "query" in class Show? For Table, use table_csv, and for List and String, use default.

```
instance Show query where
    ...
```

I know that first CSV refers to constructor name, and second to type CSV.

table_csv and csv_table are already implemented by me.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Types have names that start with an uppercase, so you should implement this as:

```
data Query = CSV CSV | Table Table | List [String]
```

We can implement an instance of `Show` by using pattern matching and thus use the correct items:

```
instance Show Query where
    show (CSV csv) = csv
    show (Table tab) = table_csv tab
    show (List items) = "List " <> show items
```

For the `List …` you can of course implement this in a different way.